# iOS - Decrypt values encrypted by AES

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need decrypt value encrypted very similar to first example in [PHP mcrypt-encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)

This is what I know:

- iv is base64 encoded
- values are base64 encoded as well
- After decoding both values from base64 then I should use decrypt method similar to [PHP mcrypt-decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php)

I am using CryptoSwift library and I created this helper method (it needs to use parameters and not values in code, it's just until I get it working):

```
class func aesDecrypt(value: String, key: String) {
    let vector = "8Z2IwsEwZ5lh27kFUmhiww=="
    let vectorData = Data(base64Encoded: vector)
    let vectorDecodedString = String(data: vectorData!, encoding: .unicode)
    print("Vector decoded: \(vectorDecodedString)") // foo

    let key = "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3"
    let manufacture = "t0gEQWTxKgrGCOqXYOIuf6syF7nm1oCrwJVsxUJvw6e2sRQ25TgmML6vzfA3YFFe"
    let keyBytes: [UInt8] = Array(key.utf8) //16
    let ivBytes: [UInt8] = [UInt8](vectorData!)//Array(vectorDecodedString!.utf8)

    let manufactureData = Data(base64Encoded: manufacture)
    let valueInBytes = [UInt8](manufactureData!)

    do {
      let aes = try AES(key: keyBytes, iv: ivBytes, blockMode: .CBC)
      let decryptedBytes = try aes.decrypt(valueInBytes)
      let decryptedData = Data(bytes: decryptedBytes)
      let decryptedString = String(bytes: decryptedBytes, encoding: .utf8)
      let decryptedString2 = String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8)
      print("decryptedString: \(decryptedString)")

    } catch let error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      // some error
    }
  }
```

Values in code I get from server. I tried AES with bytes or with strings but without luck. What's wrong with my code? How could I fix it? Thanks for help

Comment: This cannot be answered without a more formal protocol specification or, lacking that, the PHP code. Note that SO is a question / answer site, not an online debugger.

Comment: To reiterate Maarten's point, there is no "normal" way to encrypt with AES. There are many different ways to use it (most of those ways are insecure, including the code above, but they are common). I would expect that your key is incorrectly encoded (it looks like hex-encoded data, but you've treated it as a string). It is also unclear whether the decrypted data is actually a UTF-8 encoded string. (If not, then `decryptedString` will be nil.) You need to look at the PHP decryption code and make sure at every point that you have the *exact* same bytes in the Swift code.

Comment: You also need to be clear what the behavior of the above code is. Do you get an error? Is the result of `decryptedBytes` incorrect? Empty? What does "without luck" mean?